# Xamarin: Update notification text every once a second

Tags: android, xamarin

this is the notification that happens in my service class:

```
    void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
    {
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.btn_start)
            .SetContentTitle("Count Down Active!")
            .SetContentText(_2TimerRunning._hours.ToString() + _2TimerRunning._minutes.ToString() 
                            + _2TimerRunning._seconds.ToString());

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(1000, notificationBuilder.Build());

    }
```

This does work, the problem however is the "SetContentText" part.
This text is only updated once, but another timer is constantly counting down the seconds in within the braces. Unfortunately, this doesnt get updated, and even though the timer is still counting, the notificatin always reads "000000".

How can I update the text every once a second, so that there will be a ongoing countdown in within the notification?

Also, how Do I capture the click on this notification to open up the activity again? Thanks :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting notifications every second?

Comment: yes yes yes yes yes

Comment: What is _`2TimerRunning` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin: Update notification text every once a second

You can create a Task which can help you update notification text every 1 seconds, calling the `DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()` in `Task.Delay()` can resolve the repeat problem.  :

```
void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
{
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentTitle("Count Down Active!")
            .SetContentText(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(1000, notificationBuilder.Build());
        DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();//This is for repeate every 1s.
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxMwp.gif).

**Update :**

You could use a [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to implement this function, add the following code :

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(Activity2));
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
 ...
 notificationBuilder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent).SetAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: unbelievably good answer! Just one more questions: how can i catch the click onto the notifaction to open an activity? thanks so much so far!

Comment: thanks again, I am not sure on how to implement that, is there a ".click" on the notification?

Comment: okay thanks, i made it work by making the notificationmanager available in the whole class ! :)

Comment: @innomotion media, Happy coding : )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in `_2TimerRunning` the value of the time that is retrieved from this object is not valid. All other code from what I can see is working fine. So my suggestion will be to debug that object in the first place.